# Django ModelForm Not Saving to DB

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm new to Django and having a hard time figuring out how to get a model form to save to my db.  I've been following some tutorials/books and spending a lot of time on SO and I just can't figure this piece out.  The book examples i'm following is creating an IMDB type website where a user can vote movie quality (changed to games for my example).

python v. 3.6.7,
django v. 2.1.3,
postgres v. 2.2.2

Here is the model i'm trying to store and the associated manager

```
class VoteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(self, game, user):
        try:
            vote = Vote.objects.get(game=game, user=user)
        return vote
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            vote = Vote(game=game, user=user)
        return vote

class Vote(models.Model):
    objects = VoteManager()

    value = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    voted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'game')
```

Now the model form I am trying using to try and store this

```
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(), disabled=True)
    game = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, queryset=Game.objects.all(), disabled=True)
    value = forms.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ('user', 'game', 'value')
```

Template i'm using to display this information.

```
{% block main %}
<h1>{{ object }}</h1>
<p class="lead">
{{ object.summary }}
</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
 {# rating div omitted #}
  <div>
    {% if vote_form %}
      <form
          method="post"
          action="{{ vote_form_url }}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ vote_form.as_p }}
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary" >
          Vote
        </button >
      </form >
    <h3>Score: {{ object.score|default_if_none:"No score yet!" }}</h3>
    {% else %}
      <p >Log in to vote for this game</p >
    {% endif %}
  </div >
{% endblock %}
```

Finally the views to combine all of these pieces

```
class GameDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Game.objects.all_with_related_persons_and_score()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect('core:CreateVote', game_id=kwargs['pk'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            vote = Vote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(game=self.object, user=self.request.user)
            if vote.id:
                vote_form_url = reverse('core:UpdateVote', kwargs={'game_id': vote.game.id, 'pk': vote.id})
            else:
                vote_form_url = reverse('core:CreateVote', kwargs={'game_id': self.object.id})
            ctx['vote_form'] = VoteForm(instance=vote)
            ctx['vote_from_url'] = vote_form_url
        return ctx

class CreateVote(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = VoteForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['user'] = self.request.user.id
        initial['game'] = self.kwargs['game_id']
        return initial

    def get_success_url(self):
        print('never called?')
        game_id = self.kwargs['game_id']
        return reverse('core:GameDetail', kwargs={'pk': game_id})

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        game_id = self.kwargs['game_id']
        game_detail_url = reverse('core:GameDetail', kwargs={'pk': game_id})
        return redirect(to=game_detail_url)
```

My guess currently is that I just don't know how to get form from the template, many examples on here create the form when requested, the tutorial i've been following create the form in get_context_data, then pass it off to the template.  So i've been struggling to figure out how to save or validate if the form is correct.

Sorry for all the text, but these pieces are so interconnected I wanted to make sure I included everything that would be useful.  Displaying and reading from the db seem to work, if I manually go in and add votes through the admin panel I can read them successfully, when trying to write a new score through the vote button nothing happens, below is what the terminal window outputs.

```
[12/Dec/2018 20:24:34] "GET /game/85 HTTP/1.1" 200 2081
[12/Dec/2018 20:46:49] "POST /game/85 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[12/Dec/2018 20:46:49] "GET /game/vote/85/create HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[12/Dec/2018 20:46:49] "GET /game/85 HTTP/1.1" 200 2081
```

Oh maybe the url patterns might be useful.

```
app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MainPage.as_view(), name='MainPage'),
    path('games', views.GameList.as_view(), name='GameList'),
    path('game/<int:pk>', views.GameDetail.as_view(), name='GameDetail'),
    path('game/vote/<int:game_id>/create', views.CreateVote.as_view(), name='CreateVote'),
    path('game/vote/<int:game_id>/update/<int:pk>', views.UpdateVote.as_view(), name='UpdateVote'),
]
```

Thanks in advance, i've been beating my head against the wall on this one for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding type="submit" to your button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Vote</button >
```

and then in your CreateView add a form_valid method:

```
class CreateVote(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Vote
    template_name = 'folder/create_vote.html'
    form_class = VoteForm

    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        vote = form.save(commit=False)
        game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
        vote.game = game
        vote.save() # You have to save the vote for it to be added to the db.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('redirect_view'))
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, but I think I have more information to debug now.  After adding form_valid I noticed it is never called, so I added form_invalid and it is also never being called.  Like I mentioned in my original post get_initial and render are called, but nothing else.  So somehow the view doesn't know anything about the form apparently.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as an answer as it sent me down the rabbit hole I needed to fix, updating question with more details, thanks!

Comment: @bheat - Ok glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This had a painful solution, a simple typo.  In my GameDetail's get_context_data I setup data for the template to use, one of those fields was the url to post to

```
ctx['vote_from_url'] = vote_form_url
```

In the template when I attempted to reference this I misspelled it

```
 action="{{ vote_form_url }}" >
```

The frustrating thing for me is that this does not come up with an error, in the template if I put anything it defaults to the url of the parent view.  I should have noticed that POST was going to the wrong URL, but I wonder if there is a setting or log that would have told me I was referencing something in the template that doesn't exist.  Hope this recap helps someone that get stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit late and not exactly the same case but i had the same issue with FIELDSET :
**PK**(id) had to be included in the form.
Discovered this with adding this in my template:

```
{% for hidden_fields in formset %}
{{ hidden_fields.errors }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, when "SUBMIT", this showed :

> id
> Ce champ est obligatoire.
> id
> Ce champ est obligatoire.
> id
> Ce champ est obligatoire...

(champ obligatoire <=> mandatory field)

After adding the hidden TD, data were well saved :

```
    <tbody>
        {% for form in formset %}
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden">{{ form.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.ean }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.used }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Not sure it's the best way of doing but it worked for me